# firebase authentication and json

Tags: android, json, firebase

I am fairly new to firebase, used its features to my projects.

Question is:

1) Can I use firebase free services for making professional apps/client work, to handle data and authentication?

2) Should I use json data hosting sites to use url for such projects(for fetching data)? or suggest me better options.

Comment: You can use Firebase for your test app. It is paid after certain limit of users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing issues and they are off-topic here. Please read the [help] pages about how to write a good question for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase for free for a certain amount of users and traffic. You can see the limits and packages [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

I have been using Firebase's realtime database for some personal Android Apps and happy to use it. To implement it easily, Android Studio has an option for developers. Select Tools -> Firebase and Firebase Assistant will be prompted.

You can select any service you need to use in your app. The assistant even adds some pieces of code (such as dependencies and initialization for the service) needed to run the services you select.

[image: Here is the Assistant's screenshot]